# How to concatenate using ## when one of them is return from an another define

Tags: c

I have a variable length MACRO from which i need to perform an operation based on the argument that is passed.

Is there a way to get the argument with index directly using `__VA_ARGS__`?

```
#define OPERATION5(_1) (_1)

#define _GET_1ST_ARG( N,  ...) (N)

#define TOP_MACRO(...){\
    OPERATION##(_GET_1ST_ARG(1));\
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use normal functions? Function type defines are very buggy. If you want fast performance, learn about inline functions: [inline in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inline-functions-cpp/).

Comment: C does not provide any facility for picking out an element of a macro’s variable argument list using a computed index. For a constant index, you can use a fixed macro, similar to `_GET_1ST_ARG`. However, you should avoid using identifiers starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter, as these have reserved purposes in C. Additionally, this seems like it may be an X-Y problem: You are trying to do some complicated and not well supported thing Y in order to accomplish a goal X. If instead you asked about X, you might get a more useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need first expand then concatenate the identifiers with another macro pass
2. You need to remove the braces when getting the first argument. The `(` can't be concatenated.

```
// CONCATenate
#define CONCAT(a, b) a ## b
// eXpand then CONCATenate
#define XCONCAT(a, b) CONCAT(a, b)

#define OPERATION5(_1)  (_1)

// remove `(` they can't be `##` concatenated
#define GET_1ST_ARG(N,  ...)  N
#define TOP_MACRO(...)   XCONCAT(OPERATION, GET_1ST_ARG(__VA_ARGS__))(arg)

// expands `OPERATIONS5(arg)`
// expands to `(arg)`
TOP_MACRO(5)
```